# How do I query identical DB tables by year using Entity Framework Code First CTP5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Say I have a database that stores table data by year using an identical schema and one table per year. Example tables:

- MyData2009
- MyData2010
- MyData2011

I have a project using Entity Framework CTP5 (Code First) that is already working against a single year's table using the class **MyData** with a repository class that returns **IQueryable** results like this:

```
public static IQueryable<MyData> GetData(SiteDB db, string AccountNumber)
{
    return db.MyDatas.Where(oo => oo.AccountNumber == AccountNumber);
}
```

How can I refactor the above query so I can dynamically specify which table (MyData2009, MyData2010, or MyData2011) it should execute against yet still return an **IQueryable<MyData>** object type?

I thought maybe I could create **MyData2009**, **MyData2010**, **MyData2011** classes that all inherit from **MyData** and then replace the SiteDB parameter with a variable of type **DbSet<MyData>** but it looks like I can't cast **db.MyData2009s** as **DbSet<MyData>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [TPC inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx) your query must look like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetData(SiteDB db, string AccountName) where T : MyData
{
  return db.MyDatas.OfType<T>().Where(oo => oo.AccountNumber == AccountNumber);
}
```

`MyData` will be base class for all your data entities and each derived entity will be stored in its own table. When inheritance is used you need `DbSet` only for base type so be aware of using `OfType` or you will query all your tables.

The problem of this solution is that each year you will have to add new table and new entity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had planned on using Table per Hierarchy (TPH) inheritance so I don't think the solution would work in that scenario. I realize the issues with having to have an entity and table added each year. It's a MS SQL backend and there will be a couple million records per year. I'm wondering if it makes more sense to just combine the data into a single table. The tables are currently separate because that's how the legacy system worked.

Comment: The code I provided is not dependent on type of inheritance mapping used. Also all inheritance mappings suffer same problem - new table = new entity = new deploy. The reason why the system is implemented this way is most probably performance. As you mentioned each year the system adds couple million records.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks! Also, TPC is the type of inheritance I would need (like you originally said) for the scenario described, not TPH like I thought.